# Logstash logs files on finishing pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm reading from a file where logs are published by an application.

Whenever I create a pipeline all the logs are printed on screen except logs of one file, they are only printed when I finish the pipeline.

Comment: So what's your question? Can you show us your logstash configuration?

Comment: it was some encoding issue.
it's resolved.